# How to fix bugs without loading a save?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On the Xbox 360, is there any other way to fix bugs without having to load an old save? I have numerous bugs that I have looked up how to fix but I always have to load an old save to fix them. I delete all my saves so I do not have a lot of them. I have looked it up but all of the ways I've seen have risks that can mess up your whole profile. I don't want to mess my profile up because I have made it far. i need ways to fix buggs that happened in the college of winterhold one i had all my stuff in my dorm room and it refreshed and i lost all my stuff and marbelle won't give me the rest of containment main quest

Comment: You want to fix bugs, but want no risk?  I'm afraid that's not possible.  Any element of modification carries risk with it.  There's no way around that.

Comment: i know that i meant no big risk like it could freeze the game and delete your profile.

Comment: Any modification carries that risk.  It's the nature of unofficial changes.

Comment: So do you know any mods that could help on the college of winterhold or stuff that you loss when a place is refreshed

Answer (score 3):

On console, unfortunately, in many cases, if you don't have an old save to revert to, you're not going to be able to fix many of the bugs skyrim can encounter. The PC version has the advantage of the developer's console, which can fix just about any bug that can come up, but the console version does not have that. So without an old save to roll back to, in most cases, you're totally out of luck.

It *is* possible to use a PC version of Skyrim (on a friend's computer or otherwise) to be able to use the developer's console on a console version of Skyrim. Check out [this guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20121211060423/http://justpressstart.net/how-to-swap-skyrim-saves-between-pc-and-xbox360/) for details on how to do that. The exact console commands you're going to want to use are going to depend on what exactly you want to do though, and this is a little bit of a tedious process that I personally wouldn't want to have to repeat every time Skyrim encounters a remotely gamebreaking bug. The go-to solution is still going to be to load an old save, but the option to use the console is there if all else fails.

Comment: if you were to get skyrim for pc can you move your skyrim data from console to pc via flash drive

Comment: Turns out, [that is possible](http://justpressstart.net/how-to-swap-skyrim-saves-between-pc-and-xbox360/), despite my initial instincts to the contrary.

Comment: thank you so i can do it then everything just might work out